# Are Pokestop rewards only received once tapped?

Tags: pokemon-go

Often times, I am able to spin a Pokestop, but due to server issues or other app troubles, am unable to tap on the bublbes containing the items to receive them.

Force closing the app at this point generally shows that the Pokestop has already been claimed, since its now purple.

If I leave these bubbles unpopped do I still receive the rewards from that Pokestop?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, they do not need to be tapped. You can simply let them float to the top and disappear, or hit the "X" button and close it, and the items will be collected.

source: personal experience.

Comment: @MichaelMcQuade, no worries. I generally keep Arqade open on a tab and check in when new questions are asked :)

Comment: @MichaelMcQuade I can say that this is correct. Pressing X works. I didn't even know that popping the bubbles was possible until this morning.

Comment: If you only tap some of the items, purposefully ignoring some, are all items received?

Comment: All items are received, regardless of bubble integrity.

Comment: If you're in a hurry, you don't even have to let all the items appear.  You can spin the PokéStop, then press the `X` as soon as items start to appear.  You should see all the items you received, listed on the right side of the screen. ***WARNING:*** If you press the `X` too soon after spinning the PokéStop, it may give you nothing and not allow you to spin again. I've had this happen on multiple occasions, and assume it is related to a poor mobile connection.

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate further on Dragonrage's answer:
You can go to your trainer page (lower left) and press the Journal button. You will see all rewards you've gained from pokestops there, including untapped bubbles, to confirm what items you received, even when your game lost connection or crashed after spinning it and you didn't even see any rewards.